# The address fields during check-out are in the wrong order! How to order them in a logical way that customers are used to?

Tags: address

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
extensions from Amasty
```

We switched to Magento 2.4.2-p1 and the order of the Address fields during check-out is:

```
First Name
Middle Name/Initial
Last Name
Company
Street Address Street Address: Line 1
Country
State/Province
City
Zip/Postal Code
Phone number
```

Why is that? I've travelled around the world a lot and I can't think of anywhere where that would make any sense!? We do business in the United States and our customers are from the US. How can we change these to be what the customers are used to? (normal):

```
First Name
Middle Name/Initial
Last Name
Company
Street Address Street Address: Line 1
City
State
Zip
Country
Phone number
```

---

What Bhavin Gohil is suggesting below seems really hard to implement. The checkout_index_index.xml file in:

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Checkout/layout
```

**Has the following content only**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="porto_header"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

**Does anyone have a sample checkout_index_index.xml file for US standardised addresses? I searched for hours on the Internet and I feel like I'm trying to re-invent the wheel here! Surely, there are thousands of businesses in the US using Magento who have the address fields right!?!** *I really can't believe I have waste so much time on this!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add content with field name 'sortorder' like:
`<item name="country_id" xsi:type="array"> <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item> </item>`

In your theme file:
`app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_index_index.xml`:
you have to replace body content:

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">112</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">113</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">116</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <move element="logo" destination="porto_header"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I have updated my original post if you would please take a look? Basically, I only have a few lines of code in /public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml and I don't feel confident at all regarding what to add into this file. Is there a file already available out there that I could just copy?

Comment: I think the Porto theme has a backend setting for checkout fields sorting.

Comment: and also check the answer

Comment: I have contacted Porto and they replied saying this is a Magento thing and has nothing to do with the Smartwave Porto theme. I will try to upload the file. Thank you.

Comment: This worked for the Shipping address. Thank you! I see it's different for the Billing address... Would you have any idea how to change that?

Comment: @Allysin I would _strongly_ recommend making your own custom theme as a child theme of Smartwave/porto. That way if you need to update the theme then you will not need to re-apply all your customisations you have made to it so far.